# How to determine where a method came from in python (ipython)

Tags: python, ipython

I have a ipython notebook with a bunch of imports in the 
the first cell.

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 
....
```

Then, there is a call function call further on.

```
###.plot()
```

How do I determine where .plot() came from?

Comment: It's called from `###`.  I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: where did .plot() come from, pandas, matplotlib. or in general if you see a method..how do you determine the source of a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `??` will give you shortened, additional information on objects, e.g. where they have been defined.

```
>>> plt.plot?
Signature: plt.plot(*args, **kwargs)
Source:
@_autogen_docstring(Axes.plot)
...
File:      /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/pyplot.py
Type:      function
```

---

In general, you can use the special attributes `__package__` and `__module__` to find out where something is coming from.

```
>>> plt.__package__
'matplotlib'
>>> time.__module__
'time'
```

Note that if you don't know what you're dealing with, you may have to catch `AttributeError`, since only modules define `__package__` while only functions define `__module__`.

Comment: @Merlin added a solution that works for python in general.